# Почему длина числа равна undefined?

Tags: javascript

Может кто-то объяснить, почему такой код

```js
var a = 5;
alert(a.length);
```

возвращает undefined ? Вот [документация MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) . Я понимаю, что тип Number это не тип "String", но и тип "Object" у нас согласно документации это не строка, но длину массива все же считают нормально.

Comment: Потому что у чисел нет метода length... потому что оно крайне редко может пригодится. `alert( ("" + a).length )`

Comment: Потому что у числа нет такого понятия как длинна.В этом нет смысла.

Comment: var a = ("" + 5);
alert(typeof a); /// String Это уже Строка. Со строкой всё понятно. Просто я почему-то думал что если что-то уже создано, и под него было выделено память процессора, где это что-то храниться, то оно не должно быть undefined, length как бы  должно показать что у этого "нечто" есть длинна, а оно вдруг undefined. Жаль, ну ладно...

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в разных системах счисления будет разная длина строки, представляющей число, например `0xff` и `255` это одно и то же число

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в JavaScript всё явлется объектами, а у объектов разные методы(функции). Объектами являются строка, массив, числа и т.д. Все созданные объекты наследуют методы(функции) от родителя. Вот зачем нужно считать длину числа? Смысла особого нету, так как есть много разных функций для работы с числом(округление до десятых, сотых и ещё много разного), но если нужно, то можно просто из числа сделать строку `a + "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В javascript не генерируется ошибка, если идет обращение к полю, которое отсутствует.

Вместо этого проверяются все прототипы объекта, и если ни в одном из них нет искомого поля - возвращается результат `undefined`.

Именно это и происходит в коде в вопросе.